# Select li within div - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, selection

I want something [similar](http://jsfiddle.net/Q83f2/) but with little change.

What I want is, each search box ie `#box` search `<ol>` in same `<div>` where `#box` belongs

HTMl structure is like as follows

```
<div>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" /> 
<ol>
    <li>apples</li>
    <li>apricots</li>
    <li>acai</li>
    <li>blueberry</li>
    <li>bananas</li>
</ol>
</div>

<div>
<input placeholder="Search Me" id="box" type="text" /> 
<ol>
    <li>cherry</li>
    <li>coconut</li>
    <li>donut</li>
    <li>durean</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

How to modify jQuery to achieve this?

Comment: what the..? id should be unique..!

Comment: you cannot have diffrent controls with same ids

Comment: you can't use multiple times the same id in a html structure

Comment: Answer : http://jsfiddle.net/Q83f2/43/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy @Su4p also achieve same using `.parent` tag. Which one `.next` or `.parent` is best choice?

Comment: I used next at first then I red again his topic -in same <div> where #box belongs- and I used parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.box').keyup(function(){
var valThis = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
if(valThis == ""){
    $(this).parent().find('li').show();           
} else {
    $(this).parent().find('li').each(function(){
        var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        (text.indexOf(valThis) >= 0) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide();
    });
 };
 });
```

demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/N32Cd/